# Adding a filter to a JS 'parseFloat' sum

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I am trying to add a filter to my parseFloat equation.

```
$scope.getTotalOffers.forEach(function (offer) {
   $scope.countOffers.offersTotal.total += parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
});
```

So what is going on here is for each offer in the database table, I am adding up the column 'addBaskets' - for example I get 7 total offers for that 1 business. But there is another column called 'published' which is either set to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

So that one is fine as it is `offersTotal`. But I want `offersActive` and `offersDeactivated` by using `published = true` and `published = false` as filters... but how?

```
$scope.getTotalOffers = response.data.offers;

$scope.getTotalOffers.forEach(function (offer) {
   $scope.countOffers.offersTotal.total += parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
});

$scope.getTotalOffers.forEach(function (offer) {
   $scope.countOffers.offersActive.total += parseFloat(offer.addOffers); *needs published = true*
});

$scope.getTotalOffers.forEach(function (offer) {
   $scope.countOffers.offersDeactivated.total += parseFloat(offer.addOffers); *needs published = false*
});
```

I can't get my head around how to add this filter with. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is to filter the items *before* you total them up:

```
$scope.getTotalOffers = response.data.offers;

$scope.getTotalOffers.forEach(function (offer) {
   $scope.countOffers.offersTotal.total += parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
});

$scope.getTotalOffers
    .filter(function (offer) {
        return offer.published;
    })
    .forEach(function (offer) {
        $scope.countOffers.offersActive.total += parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
    });

$scope.getTotalOffers
    .filter(function (offer) {
        return !offer.published;
    })
    .forEach(function (offer) {
        $scope.countOffers.offersDeactivated.total += parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
    });
```

Here's a slightly more elegant version that uses `reduce` instead of `forEach`:

```
$scope.getTotalOffers = response.data.offers;

$scope.countOffers.offersTotal.total = $scope.getTotalOffers.reduce(function (acc, offer) {
    return acc + parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
}, 0);


$scope.countOffers.offersActive.total = $scope.getTotalOffers
    .filter(function (offer) {
        return offer.published;
    })
    .reduce(function (acc, offer) {
        return acc + parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
    }, 0);

$scope.countOffers.offersDeactivated.total = $scope.getTotalOffers
    .filter(function (offer) {
        return !offer.published;
    })
    .reduce(function (acc, offer) {
        return acc + parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
    }, 0);
```

And since the `reduce` parts are all the same, we can factor them out:

```
function addUpOffers(offers) {
    return offers.reduce(function (acc, offer) {
        return acc + parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
    }, 0);
}

$scope.getTotalOffers = response.data.offers;

$scope.countOffers.offersTotal.total = addUpOffers($scope.getTotalOffers);


$scope.countOffers.offersActive.total = addUpOffers(
    $scope.getTotalOffers.filter(function (offer) {
        return offer.published;
    })
);

$scope.countOffers.offersDeactivated.total = addUpOffers(
    $scope.getTotalOffers.filter(function (offer) {
        return !offer.published;
    })
);
```

Comment: I tried the latter solution first as it seemed cleaner etc as you suggested, however it did not work for some bizarre reason. However, your first answer worked perfectly. That is exactly where I was going wrong then, I was trying to perform the maths sum each time and attach the filter to it at the same time. 

You've made my headache go away! Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @JordanRyanMadeley I had a typo in my latter solution that I believe I've now fixed, so maybe that was the issue.

Comment: Just to expand on that, I tried the middle solution actually, then the third; both of which did not work and showed error code (either 'objectobject' or just a 0, meaning the sum wasn't adding up). But the first worked perfectly so thanks for that again.

Comment: @JordanRyanMadeley Found another issue in my 2nd and 3rd bit. I was missing the second argument to `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. One simple solution is to use `published` as a multiplication factor, or as condition in a ternary operator, but an even nicer solution is to reference the `offersActive` or `offersDeactivated` properties dynamically, based on the value of `addOffers`:

```
var props = ['offersDeactivated', 'offersActive'];
$scope.getTotalOffers.forEach(function (offer) {
   $scope.countOffers[props[+offer.published]].total += parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
   // This you already had, and can stay as it is:
   $scope.countOffers.offersTotal.total += parseFloat(offer.addOffers);
});
```

So this turns your original idea of two loops into one loop.

Comment: You should add the line from first loop to get the offersTotal.total -> `$scope.countOffers.offersTotal.total += parseFloat(offer.addOffers);`

Comment: @ Molda, I did not add that, because the question was not about that line. The OP had that line already and it worked fine. But OK, I added it just now ;-)

Comment: @trinkot i only said that because it makes sence to do it in a single loop instead of two. BTW great answer.